# Flask application not running on server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, server, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my first attempts on deploying flask application, not really sure where is the problem here, I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) guide but keep getting errors in my mod_wsgi file:

```
[Sat Nov 03 14:35:11.155499 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32192:tid 140323750705024] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 03 14:35:12.169814 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 32535:tid 140163912804224] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Sat Nov 03 14:35:12.169852 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 32535:tid 140163912804224] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Sat Nov 03 14:35:12.170269 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32535:tid 140163912804224] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 03 14:35:12.170322 2018] [core:notice] [pid 32535:tid 140163912804224] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Nov 03 14:48:42.458225 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32535:tid 140163912804224] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 03 14:48:43.466614 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 32681:tid 140491172063104] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Sat Nov 03 14:48:43.466645 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 32681:tid 140491172063104] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Sat Nov 03 14:48:43.467119 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32681:tid 140491172063104] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 03 14:48:43.467135 2018] [core:notice] [pid 32681:tid 140491172063104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

my application looks like this:

```
--www
----catalog
-----|-- catalog
---------|-- __init__.py
---------|--  model.py
-----|-- CatalogApp.wsgi
```

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/catalogApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName server_ip
                WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/catalog/catalogApp.wsgi"
                <Directory /var/www/catalog/catalog/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo nano catalogApp.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/catalog/")

from catalog import app as application
application.secret_key = ''
```

Comment: Can you run your app locally ? Did you do step 3 ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar it is working fine locally, but I still can't make it to work on the server. I didn't do step three since the application is not build on a virtual env locally.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. Reading that article, it's very long and complex to follow. If you really want to host your application, check out pythonanywhere, free python hosting service or heroku (you just push to github and in heroku web dashboard import from your repo).

Comment: I am in exact same boat. Did you manage to find solution?